# Prevent observables from being started unless another observable finishes it's job

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-java

In my app client uses services backed by `Observable`s. Each service call is session based, so that a session has to be started before a business-service method can be called.

In order to init session I made an `Observable` that does it. My problem is that whenever client uses more than one business-service in parallel, session initialization gets duplicated. Client code is session-agnostic. I need a way to init session in such a way that the session observable only gets called once(when the first business-service method gets called). Basically all subsequent business-observers have to wait for condition(session initialization). Can you draw a pattern for it?

Client code would look like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    itemService.getItems(10).subscribe(new Observer<List<Item>>() {..});
    userService.getProfile().subscribe(new Observer<List<Profile>>() {..});
}
```

While there're 2 calls, I need to make the session `Observable` execute once only and make business `Observable`s wait for the session initialization to complete and then start doing its' job.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but maybe you can take a look at publish-connect pattern here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Connectable-Observable-Operators

Answer (score 2):

If the session initialization is an Observable, then you can delay all other Observables that depend on it, using the `delay` operator with the session initialization Observable as parameter: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#delay%28rx.functions.Func1%29

Comment: It's almost what I need except that delaying observable has to be the first to be executed. Delay seems to execute delayed observable and apply delay Observable after.

Comment: You can also use flatMap which can be understood as running a new Observable after each emission on the source Observable. But I'm inclined to say that you're probably thinking at the problem from the wrong perspective. Observables shouldn't be "jobs", they should be just event streams, or data streams. If Observable A and B depend on values from X, then you need to start looking at operators such as `flatMap` or `map`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a session Observable implemented, one possible solution would be to convert it to an [AsyncSubject](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Subject#asyncsubject). It would execute only once and would emit only the last item (or only item) to each subscriber.

Depending on how your session initialization code works, it may be more elegant to use one of the [Async](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Async-Operators) operators such as [Async.start()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Async-Operators#start) or [Async.startFuture()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Async-Operators#startfuture) to create your session observable.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't wrap my head around your suggestion. Could you give an example? I edited the question to clarify it a bit. Thanks.